# Array of pointers to a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct Oft{
   int   mode;
   int   refCount;
} OFT;

typedef struct proc{
   struct proc *next;
   int    uss, usp;
   int    pid;                // add pid for identify the proc
   int    status;             // status = FREE|READY|RUNNING|SLEEP|ZOMBIE    
   int    ppid;               // parent pid
   OFT    *fd[10];    
   int    kstack[1024];      // per proc stack area
}PROC;
```

How would I initialize and use my *fd[10] variable?

assume that I have

```
PROC *p;
```

Is this the correct way to initialize its *fd[10]?

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    p->fd[i] = (OFT *) malloc (sizeof(OFT));
    (*p->fd)[0] = Some OFT object?   
}
```

why is p->fd[i] always equal to null when I do the following checking?

```
if (p->fd[i] == NULL)
    //Do sometiong
```

Comment: You must initialize `p` first before you initialize its members. Also check the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Assume that I initialized it. I don't want to post more code that necessary

Answer (score 2):

```
p->fd[i] = malloc(sizeof(OFT));
```

is correct, as long as you've provided space for p to point to, by using `malloc()` or by making it point to some PROC variable. Note you don't need to cast, since `malloc()` returns a `void *` which is cast to any type of pointer automatically. You should, however, check if `malloc()` returns `NULL`.

```
(*p->fd)[0]
```

is wrong and will result in a compiler error. If you have an OFT object named myoft; you can assign it just like you did with malloc; of course, since fd[x] is a pointer, you want to have the address of the object:

```
p->fd[x] = &myoft;
```

If you want to access one of the components of one of your OFTs, you could, for example, use

```
p->fd[x]->refCount++;
```

I can't answer the last question, why `if (p->fd[i] == NULL)` is always true, unless you provide a complete example of your code.

Comment: if I do **p->fd[x] = &myoft** in a function and exit that function and check one of its components after, it returns values different from the ones that I assigned! Any idea?

Comment: Oh I just realized that the return value of malloc is NULL. I did check p->fd[i] after malloc and it's still null!